# IBM Mobilefirst Foundation Platform 6.3 - Tomcat not responding after deploying runtime

Tags: tomcat, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am building a new IBM Mobilefirst Foundation Platform 6.3 with the following configuration:
 1. Tomcat -1.7.0.54
 2. JDK - Oracle JDK 1.7.0_71-b14
 3. DB - MySQL 5.6.22
 4. OS - RHEL 6.5

It works fine all the way till MobileFirst Console. After I deploy a runtime using server configuration tool, tomcat stop responding, including the stop command. I have to manually kill it. If I undeploy the runtime, tomcat works fine.
The war file is a simple Hello MobileFirst project created using studio v6.3.

I rebuild the same using WAS Liberty Core 8.5.5.4 on the same host, it works fine. I am speculating there is something to do with JMX,, may be the port is blocked. I tried jconsole to connect to the tomcat instance, it connects and I can see the monitoring chart.

Any idea?

Below are last 70 lines of catalina.out:

```
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:02 PM com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource createResourceRefDatasource
FINE: Entering, resourceRefName=jdbc/WorklightDS [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:02 PM com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource extractDbTypeFromURL
FINE: Entering: url = jdbc:mysql://137.57.137.41:3306/WRKLGHT [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:02 PM com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource extractDbTypeFromURL
FINE: Driver class name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:02 PM com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource extractDbTypeFromURL
FINE: Extracted DB type = MYSQL [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:02 PM com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource afterPropertiesSet
INFO: FWLSE0192I: JNDI resource jdbc/WorklightDS is mapped to MYSQL DB type [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:02 PM com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource afterPropertiesSet
FINE: Discovered DB type =MYSQL [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:02 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'WorklightPU'
15  WorklightPU  WARN   [localhost-startStop-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/var/tomcat/wle1/Worklight/devworklight/worklight-jee-library.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:02 PM com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsHttpServiceImpl getServerProperties
FINE: Analytics is disabled; data will not be forwarded to IWAP because wl.analytics.url property is not set.
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils globalScopeLookup
FINE: JNDI Access via globalScopeLookup to ibm.worklight.topology.platform => Tomcat
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils applicationScopeLookup
WARNING: Access to JNDI property ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode with null context path
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils applicationScopeLookup
FINE: JNDI Access via applicationScopeLookup in null to ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode => Standalone
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory getRuntimeMBeanHandler
FINE: found Tomcat runtime
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.GeneralUtil scanAllIPv4Interfaces
FINE: found IP address:/fe80:0:0:0:250:56ff:feaf:169%2 [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.GeneralUtil scanAllIPv4Interfaces
FINE: found IP address:/137.57.137.10 [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext AuthenticationContext
FINE: Create authentication context [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal set
FINE: Set ProjectLocal: devworklight
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1365)
    at com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal.set(BaseProjectLocal.java:54)
    at com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:95)
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.BaseProjectLocal set
FINE: Set ProjectLocal returned: true [project devworklight]
541  WorklightPU  INFO   [localhost-startStop-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
569  WorklightPU  INFO   [localhost-startStop-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "com.worklight.database.WorklightMySQLDBDictionary".
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.server.database.api.WorklightDataSource afterPropertiesSet
INFO: FWLSE0187I: jdbc/WorklightReportsDS data source is disabled. No connection opened.  [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean createNativeEntityManagerFactory
INFO: Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'WorklightReportsPU'
1  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [localhost-startStop-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/var/tomcat/wle1/Worklight/devworklight/worklight-jee-library.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.report.impl.GadgetReportsServiceImpl loadProperties
INFO: FWLSE0186I: Application raw reports are disabled. [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.report.impl.AnalyticsServiceImpl loadProperties
FINE: AnalyticsServiceImpl.loadProperties [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.mgmt.impl.ApplicationManagementImpl ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl
FINE: ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.core.jmx.ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl
FINE: ProjectManagementMXBeanImpl [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils applicationScopeLookup
FINE: JNDI Access via applicationScopeLookup in devworklight to ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid => Dev_Worklight
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.JNDIFromPropertiesUtil getPropertiesFromFile
WARNING: File  not found. Context path is __globalscope__
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils globalScopeLookup
FINE: JNDI Access via globalScopeLookup to ibm.worklight.admin.serverid => null
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyJMXRegister register
FINE:  detected single server mode. [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyJMXRegister register
INFO: FWLSE2008I: MBean registration succeeded for: com.worklight.common.server.jmx.api:type=ProjectManagement_Dev_Worklight,qualifier=devworklight [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator contextInitialized
FINE: Start JMX initialization [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter setSyncRequired
INFO: FWLSE0273I: Set sync required to 'true' [project devworklight]
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.JNDIUtils applicationScopeLookup
FINE: JNDI Access via applicationScopeLookup in devworklight to ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid => Dev_Worklight
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.jmx.MBeanConnectorFactory getRuntimeMBeanHandler
FINE: found Tomcat runtime
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM com.worklight.common.util.jmx.RuntimeMBeanHandler getRMIConnection
INFO: Establishing RMI connection on localhost with port number 8686
Jan 14, 2015 4:19:03 PM RuntimeMBeanHandler getRMIConnection()
FINE: JMXServiceURL = service:jmx:rmi://localhost:8686/jndi/rmi://localhost:8686/jmxrmi
```

Comment: Add logs from the server

Answer (score 2):

I opened a PMR with IBM. It turns out MobileFirst v6.3 and earlier have this problem with certain configuration of fedora family of Linux (Red Hat 6, in my case) and Windows 2012. What happened was Tomcat HTTP service not started when tomcat is start/restart with MobileFirst runtime installed. The latest iFix of v6.3 addressed this issue. This is not an issue with Windows 2008 or Redhat 7.

Comment: do you have the PMR #?

Comment: Here u go: 74374,49R,000

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your server's JMX configuration in Tomcat is not correct.

Your current URL is:
 `JMXServiceURL = service:jmx:rmi://localhost:8686/jndi/rmi://localhost:8686/jmxrmi`

The above syntax is used when Tomcat is used behind a firewall and in any case the port number (8686) cannot be the same.

Worklight uses the above syntax when the JNDI property "ibm.worklight.admin.rmi.serverPort" is defined in the server.xml file. If there is no use of a firewall this property *must be removed*.

Check his configuration according to the following documentation topic: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/t_optional_config_app_server_tomcat.html

Comment: The project runtime was created using server configuration tool and I did not add JNDI property "ibm.worklight.admin.rmi.serverPort".